# Mythtv - have to kill and restart backend at every boot

Tags: startup, upstart, autostart, mythbuntu, mythtv

Ubuntu 16.04, fresh install.

I don't know what I've done to mess it up, but I have to kill mythbackend (which for some reason is running with root privileges so requires `sudo` to kill) and start it as my regular user.

Understandably, my wife does not accept having to do this to get the TV working.

So I guess my question is, how do I get it to stop starting up on login as superuser, and then how do I get it to start as my regular user? I would hate to try and do both by running a startup script of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently a form of this problem has been going on since at least 2008. Several delay/sleep/pause tactics seem to fix the problem but it keeps coming back.

Especially if you have hdhomerun tuners and a solid state disk. When the system boots, it gets to tuner verification before the network is fully functional. Then the tuner acquisition fails and live tv simply does not work, any shows recorded after reboot will seem to exist but will not playback.

Restarting the backend after network communication is established will fix the problem but after the next reboot, the problem returns.

[This post on the MythTV Forum](https://forum.mythtv.org/viewtopic.php?t=1467) offers a possible fix:

> You could just add a `sleep 10` (or however long it takes for your HDHR to get up and running.) That would go in the `mythtv-backend.service` file. But, if you modify the one in `/lib/systemd/system`, then if a new version is released, your
>   changes will go away. So the proper solution is to put the `.service` file in `/etc/systemd/system`
>
> Of course then you'd miss any updates to the official version in `/lib`. You just need to be aware of that.
>
> You could do this. Make sure you understand every command below before starting:
>
> stop the backend:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl stop mythtv-backend
> sudo --login systemctl edit --full mythtv-backend
> ```
>
> add:
>
> ```
> ExecStartPre=sleep 10
> ```
>
> (or append: `;sleep 10` to an existing `ExecStartPre` line)
>
> reload:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl daemon-reload
> ```
>
> restart the backend:
>
> ```
> sudo systemctl start mythtv-backend
> ```

There is a potentially more comprehensive solution also mentioned, but this is suggested as a basic workaround.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/829883)

Comment: I agree  that I should have included quoted text instead of a link but I don't want to imply that I fully understand the workaround myself. The 'more comprehensive' workaround worked for me in Ubuntu 17.04 and earlier but changes in 17.10 prevent my novice methods of file manipulation (sudo gedit, sudo nautilus). I can no longer make the linked instructions work at my skill level. Since it is already April, I am waiting for 18.04 before I attempt to ask new questions in the linked thread. I expect the updated workaround to be slightly different.

Answer (score 0):

Your mythbackend should be running as a mythtv process...

```
~$ ps auxc|grep myth
mythtv    3706  0.1  0.5 4930284 89092 ?       Ssl  Aug03   1:29 mythbackend
```

And your username should be in the mythtv group...

```
~$ groups
{username} adm dialout fax cdrom sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev fuse lpadmin scanner sambashare vboxusers kismet mythtv input wireshark
```

If it's not, then...

```
sudo adduser your_username mythtv
```

Then logout and log back in to enable.

Comment: So, when it boots up mythtv is running as a mythtv process, and my username is in the group. The backend, when run as a mythtv process, can't seem to access the storage, so won't play or record tv. Doesn't work when running frontend with sudo, either.

When I kill the backend and start it under my username everything works. Is this a permissions issue?

Comment: When started normally, can you see the list of recorded programs? If so, what happens when you select one to play? Does http://http://localhost:6544/ work?

Comment: I can see the list, but it says the file cannot be found. After restarting the backend it works normally. I don't see anything at http://localhost:6544

I checked whether mythtv was in the mythtv group and it was not; after adding it, I get a different error when trying to watch live tv - it claims the tuner is busy. Recordings still don't work until restarting it.

Comment: I've fixed it for now by setting rc.local to pkill mythbackend and then starting mythbackend as the particular user that I use to get it working right. Seems a bit dirty; will keep working towards a correct solution.